# Different behaviour of unscoped between rails 3 and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have just upgraded an application from Rails 3.2.8 to Rails 4.0.2 and I've got an strange behaviour with a model that has a "default_scope" defined.

The questions is that it seems like "unscoped" (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped) doesn't work in Rails 4 in the same way it used to do in Rails 3.

The problem raises when I try to chain "unscoped" with another "scope". In Rails 3 it worked fine by first removing default scope and then applying the second scope. In Rails 4, it adds the default scope always.

I have a Model defined this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...... 

  # set a default scope to be aplied to EVERY query. to override this use "unscoped", for example: User.unscoped.all
  def self.default_scope
    where :active => true
  end

  # users that can be shown in the application
  scope :not_hidden, where(:hidden => false)
  
  .....
end
```

And here are some examples on how scope and unscoped are working on 3.2.8 and 4.0.2:

### User.all  (OK)

(3.2.8)

```
User.all         
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."active" = 't'
```

(4.0.2)

```
User.all
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."active" = 't'
```

### User.unscoped (OK)

(3.2.8)

```
User.unscoped
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
```

(4.0.2)

```
User.unscoped
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
```

### User.unscoped.not_hidden (FAIL)

(3.2.8) (OK)

```
User.unscoped.not_hidden
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."hidden" = 'f'
```

(4.0.2) (FAIL)

```
User.unscoped.not_hidden
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."active" = 't' AND "users"."hidden" = 'f'
```

### User.not_hidden.unscoped (OK)

(3.2.8) (OK)

```
User.not_hidden.unscoped
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
```

(4.0.2) (OK)

```
User.not_hidden.unscoped
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
```

Can anybody tell me if I'm missing something on how default scope and unscoped works in Rails 4?

Answer (score 3):

That's desired behaviour (see [Removing All Scoping](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#removing-all-scoping) in the guides).

> Note that chaining unscoped with a scope does not work. In these
>   cases, it is recommended that you use the block form of unscoped:
>
> ```
> Client.unscoped {   
>   Client.created_before(Time.zone.now) 
> }
> ```

Comment: I have just found a solution.

I have changed not_hidden scope defintion from:

    scope :not_hidden, where(:hidden => false)
To:
def self.not_hidden
    where(:hidden => false)
  end
And it works fine!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a solution.

I have changed not_hidden scope defintion from:

```
scope :not_hidden, where(:hidden => false)
```

To:

```
def self.not_hidden
  where(:hidden => false)
end
```

And it works fine!!!!